# C# Console App - Make a Soap Call with Custom Header

Tags: c#, .net, soap

I need to make a call to a SOAP web service from a C# .net console application.  The service requires a custom UsernameToken header to be in the call.  I can add this header in the app.config file like this and it works:

```
        <headers>
          <wsse:Security mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
              <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
              <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
          </wsse:Security>
        </headers>
```

However, I actually need to make this call multiple times in a loop, passing in a different username and password each time.  How can I do this?  I don't seem to be able to access this value from code.

Comment: Please share your code that calls the service and tell us where you want the loop to be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have some example code from one of my projects:

```
public static MessageHeader<SecurityHeaderType> GetSecurityHeader(string userName, string passWord, string nonce)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)
        {
            userName = string.Empty;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(passWord))
        {
            passWord = string.Empty;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nonce))
        {
            nonce = string.Empty;
        }

        var usernameToken = new UsernameToken();
        var securityHeader = new SecurityHeaderType { UsernameToken = usernameToken };
        // ReSharper disable once SpecifyACultureInStringConversionExplicitly
        string now = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        var tokenManager = new UsernameTokenManager();
        var passwordDigest = tokenManager.CreatePasswordDigest(Convert.FromBase64String(nonce), now, passWord);
        securityHeader.UsernameToken.Created = now;
        securityHeader.UsernameToken.Nonce = nonce;
        securityHeader.UsernameToken.Password = passwordDigest;
        securityHeader.UsernameToken.Username = userName;

        var header = new MessageHeader<SecurityHeaderType> { Content = securityHeader, Actor = "" };

        return header;
    }

    Public void CallService(){
 const string userName = "username";
        const string passWord = "password";
        const string nonce = "nonce";
        var securityHeader = SecurityHeaderHelper.GetSecurityHeader(userName, passWord, nonce);

        using (new OperationContextScope(_client.InnerChannel))
        {
            var untypedSecurityHeader = securityHeader.GetUntypedHeader("Security", Constants.SecurityHeaderWSSE);
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(untypedSecurityHeader);

           var dummyRequest = new DummyRequest();

            try
            {
                var testResponse = _client.Call(dummyRequest);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Assert.Fail(exp.Message);
            }               
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, Declan.  Sorry for the slow reply on my part.  Your code looks to be doing essentially the same thing that I ended up doing so I will mark your answer as correct.  For reference, I ended up just doing this: using (new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
  {
    SOAPSecurtyHeader security = new SOAPSecurtyHeader();
    security.Username = "username";
    security.Password = "password";
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(security);
  }